# Finite State Machine with Its States Controlled by Two Processes

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, fsm

I'm trying to code a finite state machine (FSM) with VHDL language right now (and I'm actually new to VHDL). What I'm trying to achieve is, whenever the machine is in *S11*, the *STint* will decrease respectively with the *CLK2* (So I can control how fast the decreasement is). However, *S0* until *S10* are controlled by *CLK1*.

Here is my code:

```
begin
 process(state,DI,HI,QI,rst)      
 begin
    case State is
      when S0 =>
          DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0'; STint <= 9;
        if DI'EVENT and DI = '1' then Nextstate <= S4;
          elsif HI'EVENT and HI = '1' then Nextstate <= S2;
          elsif QI'EVENT and QI = '1' then Nextstate <= S1;
          elsif rst'EVENT and rst = '1' then Nextstate <= S10;
        else Nextstate <= S0; end if;
      when S1 =>
          DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
        if DI'EVENT and  DI = '1' then Nextstate <= S5;
          elsif HI'EVENT and HI = '1' then Nextstate <= S3;
          elsif QI'EVENT and QI = '1' then Nextstate <= S2;
          elsif rst'EVENT and rst = '1' then Nextstate <= S10;
        else Nextstate <= S1; end if;
      when S2 =>
          DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
        if DI'EVENT and DI = '1' then Nextstate <= S6;
          elsif HI'EVENT and HI = '1' then Nextstate <= S4;
          elsif QI'EVENT and QI = '1' then Nextstate <= S3;
          elsif rst'EVENT and rst = '1' then Nextstate <= S10;
        else Nextstate <= S2; end if;  
      when S3 =>
          DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
        if DI'EVENT and DI = '1' then Nextstate <= S7;
          elsif HI'EVENT and HI = '1' then Nextstate <= S5;
          elsif QI'EVENT and QI = '1' then Nextstate <= S4;
          elsif rst'EVENT and rst = '1' then Nextstate <= S10;
        else Nextstate <= S3; end if;       
      when S4 =>
          DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
        if DI'EVENT and DI = '1' then Nextstate <= S8;
          elsif HI'EVENT and HI = '1' then Nextstate <= S6;
          elsif QI'EVENT and QI = '1' then Nextstate <= S5;
          elsif rst'EVENT and rst = '1' then Nextstate <= S10;
        else Nextstate <= S4; end if;  
      when S5 =>
          DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
        if DI'EVENT and DI = '1' then Nextstate <= S9;
          elsif HI'EVENT and HI = '1' then Nextstate <= S7;
          elsif QI'EVENT and QI = '1' then Nextstate <= S6;
          elsif rst'EVENT and rst = '1' then Nextstate <= S10;
        else Nextstate <= S5; end if;  
      when S6 =>
        DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
          Nextstate <= S11;      
      when S7 =>
        DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '1'; ST <= '0';
          QOint <= -1;
          Nextstate <= S11;
      when S8 =>
        DO <= '0'; HO <= '1'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '0';
          HOint <= HOint -1;
          Nextstate <= S11;
      when S9 =>
        DO <= '0'; HO <= '1'; QO <= '1'; ST <= '0';
          HOint <= HOint -1;
          QOint <= QOint -1;
          Nextstate <= S11;
      when S10 =>                 
        DOint <= 9; HOint <= 9; QOint <= 9; STint <= 9;
          Nextstate <= S0;
      when others => null;          
    end case;
  end process;

  process(CLK1)   
  begin
   if CLK1'EVENT and CLK1 = '1' then
      State <= Nextstate;
   end if;
  end process;

  process(state,CLK2)
  begin
   case State is 
       when S11 =>
        DO <= '0'; HO <= '0'; QO <= '0'; ST <= '1';
    if CLK2'EVENT and CLK2 = '1' then STint <= STint -1;
    elsif STint <= 0 then Nextstate <= S0; end if;
       when others => null;
    end case;
  end process;
```

I've tried many alternatives, such as using the *CLK1* as the clock for the *STint* decreasement, but it didn't work well because the other *int*(s) will decrease again and again. 

For further information, this FSM is actually similar to vending machine, except in *S11*, a timer will start the countdown then go to the next state, which is *S0*. The other states is just for the inputs (such as the money) and the outputs (such as the changes). In *S11*, the *ST* LED will be turned on as long as the timer still counting down.

Is there any way I can achieve this? I would really glad if someone could point me out why my code won't work. It seems like whenever the machine is in *S11*, it cannot change its state. This is how my code looks like in TINA: 
[image]

Thank you very much. Have a nice day! 
PS: The timer is shown in *STcount* outputs

Comment: First, to help us to help you, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then two tips on VHDL : clocked process shall have only CLK (and potentially asynchronous RST) in the sensivity list, also write only one clk edge detection in your process. Then to use 2 different clocks, read up about "clock domain crossing".

Comment: 1/ Your code is full of clocks. Remove all your `XX'EVENT and XX = '1'` except where XX is your main clock. 2/ Every input signal needs a synchroniser circuit. After that you can check if it is high or low. 3/ If this is supposed to be a real circuit add switch de-bouncing. 4/ replace the 1K clock with a 1K 'valid' from the 2K with a divide-by-two.

Comment: You cannot drive signals from multiple processes. Don't use multiple clocks: use timers/delay counters.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues in your approach:

- Multiple clocks for the FSM. You should avoid to have multiple clocks in your designs and use it only when necessary. To have two clocks for a given circuit is ask for problems.
- Use a single clock. If you want to keep the control using the clock build a separate circuit to control just the clock generation. A counter can solve for a simple design. More complex design may require the use of specific hardware for clock generation(e.g PLL).
- You are assigning to signals in different process at least DO. This should not synthesize.

I suggest you to rethink your state machine control and to understand the limits for the decreasing speed.